# Конвертация CSV в XLSX с помощью node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, csv

Конвертирую CSV в XLSX на node.js с помощью библиотеки ExcelJS 
(украдено отсюда: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs)

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');

filename_in = 'test.csv';
filename_out = 'test.xlsx';

var workbook_in = new Excel.Workbook();
var workbook_out = createAndFillWorkbook();

workbook_in.csv.readFile(filename_in)
    .then(function(worksheet) {

        workbook_out.xlsx.writeFile(filename_out)
            .then(function() {
                console.log('Computed');
        });

    });


function createAndFillWorkbook(){
     var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
     return workbook;
};
```

Возвращает в файл байткод вида:

```
504b 0304 0a00 0000 0800 3280 7d4d 302b
1350 2e01 0000 7f03 0000 1300 0000 5b43
.... .... .... .... .... .... .... ....
```

В чем я неправ?

Comment: Поясните? Создается текстовый файл с набором шестнадцатеричных цифр? Потому что у меня Ваш код, скопированный без малейших изменений, создает нормальный xlsx-файл (который действительно начинается с байтов `50 4b 03 04 ...`).

Comment: @Yaant Такой файл не открывается при помощи Excel. Когда же открываешь его в текстовом редакторе, то показывает байт-код, хотя обычно xlsx-файл выглядит так: `PK     ! |ll      [Content_Types].xml ў(`, т.е. он уже расшифрован.

Answer (score -1):

```
var Excel = require("exceljs");
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

filename_in = "test.csv";
filename_out = "test.xlsx";

workbook.csv.readFile(filename_in).then(function (worksheet) {
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filename_out).then(function () {
        console.log("Computed");
    });
});
```

Вот рабочий вариант, но кодировка "windows-1251" слетает. Есть идеи?

Comment: Обратите внимание, вы дали ответ. На ответ вам никто не ответит. [Задайте новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и сошлитесь на текуший, если есть взаимосвязь. Это сообщение, пожалуйста, удалите.